# What's the meaning of for...in in Lua?

Tags: lua

I was playing with the following code and got confused.

```
function square(iteratorMaxCount,currentNumber)
   if currentNumber<iteratorMaxCount
   then
      currentNumber = currentNumber+1
      return currentNumber, currentNumber*currentNumber
   end

end

for i,n in square,3,0
do
   print(i,n)
end
```

My confusing point is: what is exactly `for i,n in square,3,0`? I tried this in terminal, and got the following error.

```
stdin:2: attempt to compare number with nil
stack traceback:
    stdin:2: in function 'for iterator'
    stdin:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

Any comments are greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** I tried it again. This time, I have put spaces among "for i,n in square,3,0" and it works out well.

Comment: Did you maybe mean `for i,n in square(3,0)` - which would make more sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the syntax of Lua's **generic `for` loop**.

Quote from the [Reference Manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.3.5):

> A for statement like
>
> ```
>  for var_1, ···, var_n in explist do block end
> ```
>
> is equivalent to the code:
>
> ```
> do
>   local f, s, var = explist
>   while true do
>     local var_1, ···, var_n = f(s, var)
>     if var_1 == nil then break end
>     var = var_1
>     block
>   end
> end
> ```
>
> Note the following:
>
> - explist is evaluated only once. Its results are an iterator function, a state, and an initial value for the first iterator variable.
> - f, s, and var are invisible variables. The names are here for explanatory purposes only.

There are few more notes in the original text, but we can skip them for now. See [Reference Manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.3.5) for the full version with all notes.

Let's consider the basic usage of `pairs` first:

```lua
for k, v in pairs({5, 6, 7}) do
   print(k, v)
end
```

A call to `pairs` returns an iterator and a state for generic for. The third value is automatically assigned `nil`. We could be more descriptive in our code and change the above sample to:

```lua
local f, s, var = pairs({5, 6, 7})
for k, v in f, s, var do
   print(k, v)
end
```

Please note that both samples behave in the same way. We could step up our game and completely get rid off `pairs`:

```lua
for k, v in next, {5, 6, 7}, nil do
   print(k, v)
end
```

`next` function takes two arguments: a table and a key and then returns key and value of the next member of the table. This means that the above sample is also an equivalent of the previous samples.

In the end there are up to three things expected to be `for k,v in <HERE> do`:

- an **iterator** - function that will be called each iteration to assign values to variables declared in `for <HERE> in`,
- a **state** - value that is passed in each iteration to the **iterator**,
- an **initial value** - value passed as second argument to the **iterator** in the first iteration of the loop.

Functions like `pairs`, `ipairs` or `gmatch` simply return some of those expected things as illustrated in `pairs` examples above.

In your case the **iterator** is `square`, **state** is `3` and **initial value** is `0`. This means the `i, n` will have their values assigned as in: `i, n = square(3, i or 0)` (`0` in first iteration, then the value of `i` from the previous iteration).

Programming in Lua also has a nice chapter about it: [PIL - 4.3.5 - Generic for](https://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.5.html). I highly encourage you to read it. Actually, I highly encourage you to read the whole PIL, as it is a quite good starting point to programming in Lua.

Comment: I mean, I tried the following code, and it is really confusing. local a,b,c = pairs({5,6,7})
print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
the output is:  function: 0x559ba50fff10;  table: 0x559bafb8b50; nil

Comment: oh. I see your point. pairs({5,6,7}) would return three elements, one is the next function, the second one is the table {5,6,7}, and the third one is the nil ?

Comment: I will memorize it.

Comment: @kkxx Changed the structure of the answer quite a bit. Maybe this will help you more.