# Explaination of for loop syntax in given lua script

Tags: lua

I need help understanding this **`for _,v in next,keys,nil do`** line in the below lua script.

Here we are fetching i think a list from redis database and then iterating over it. But i couldn't understand how this for loop syntax is working.

```lua
local keys=redis.call('keys', 'someRegexPattern');

for _,v in next,keys,nil do
  -- doing somethings with variable v
end

return something;
```

I know that `_` is used as placeholders to hold values we will not be using in the loop. But how do we have 3 variables in RHS and only 2 variables in LHS

Thanks for helping

Comment: `for _, v in next, keys, nil do` does the same like `for _, v in pairs(keys) do` (but without calling `pairs`). `next` returns the value of the next entry of a lua table.
(see, [Lua Manual](https://www.lua.org/pil/7.3.html))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the meaning of for...in in Lua?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58714058/whats-the-meaning-of-for-in-in-lua)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the generic form of the `for` loop in Lua. The three arguments on the right side of the `in` are the iterator, the state and the initial value:

```lua
for value, other variables... in iterator, state, initialValue do ... end
```

On each iteration the state and the current value (on the first iteration the initial value) are passed to the iterator, and it returns the next value, possibly with additional iteration variables, until the returned value is falsey.

In your case the iterator is the `next` function. It takes a table and a key name, and returns the next key of the table alongside the value of that key from the table. If the key is `nil`, it returns the first entry of the table.

For more technical details on how it works you can see the [Lua Reference Manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.3.5)

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that `pairs(t)` returns exactly that: `next, t, nil`; si it's in fact equivalent, except there's one less function call. My guess is that this was a bad attempt at being smart and "optimizing" the code by removing the one function call.