# Further details needed to understand 'for' loop in Lua

Tags: for-loop, lua

I'm having trouble understanding how this type of for loop works.
Can someone please explain this for me.

```
hello = {"hello1", "hello2", "hello3"}
for i, v in pairs(hello) do
    print(i, v)
end
```

Comment: A short description is [here](https://www.lua.org/pil/7.3.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Explaination of for loop syntax in given lua script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58830810/explaination-of-for-loop-syntax-in-given-lua-script)

Comment: Please read at least the first 3 chapters of the Lua manual befor using it. It is very short and well written. That makes a lot more sense than trying to understand Lua code without knowing any basics.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to [the manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.3.5); it explains in great detail how the generic for loop works.